# representations of Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am studying irreducible representations of Lie algebras when our filed is of positive characteristic, I need an explicit explanation with example (or an article) which describes the differences what be appeared when we suppose our field is GF(2)?

Comment: in fact I need a practical and small example of description of all irreducible representation of a simple lie algebra over GF(3) and compare with the case of GF(2)?

Comment: What source are you studying this from?

Comment: Nowadays I am studying a book from Helmut strade "Modular Lie Algebras and their representations".

Comment: Ok, not that familiar with this from the Lie algebra side. Are you studying representations as restricted Lie algebras, or more generally? If restricted, I can write a bit coming from the side of algebraic groups, but I am not sure how useful that will be.

Comment: certainly it will be helpful to have a frame of this study, Thank you if you could let me know about your description.

Comment: Hmm, as I started writing I realized that it may be a bit complicated, since the most simple examples ($sl_2$ and $sl_3$) each fail to be simple in one of those characteristics, so my examples might not be that useful.